# Cannot delete file in C#.net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am first creating Bitmap image file and saving it to some temp location. Later using that file to read in BitmapImage object to compare it with other file. Once comparison is done, I want to delete file but then it throws exception that file is being used by another process. How can I delete this file?

Here is my code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string strPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        GC.Collect();

        if (txtLoginImage.Text != "")
        {
            string strFileName = txtLoginImage.Text.Substring(txtLoginImage.Text.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            Bitmap MainImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(txtLoginImage.Text);

            Bitmap NewImage = ConvertToGrayScale(MainImg);

            NewImage.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Temp\\" + strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            NewImage.Dispose();

            Uri SourceUri = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Temp\\" + strFileName);
            BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();

            source.UriSource = SourceUri;

            IrisSystem.Class.BLL.User_BLL ubll = new IrisSystem.Class.BLL.User_BLL();
            DataSet dsUserData= ubll.getlist();

            bool isMatchFound = false;

            if (dsUserData != null && dsUserData.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dsUserData.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Uri TargetUri = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Grayscale\\" + item["GrayScaleImgName"]);
                    BitmapImage Target = new BitmapImage(TargetUri);

                    if (source.IsEqual(Target))
                    {
                        IrisSystem.frmHome frm= new IrisSystem.frmHome();
                        frm.strFullName = item["FullName"].ToString();
                        frm.ShowDialog();
                        Form.ActiveForm.Close();
                        isMatchFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    Target = null;
                }

                if (!isMatchFound)
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Credential..","Invalid Operation");
            }
            File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Temp\\" + strFileName);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select image", "Login Error");
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to dispose *all* the bitmaps, for example `MainImg` is not disposed. Consider using `using` construct instead of calling `.Dispose()`, also use `Path.Combine` to concat paths to the resources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your `Bitmap` objects are disposed properly.

You are not disposing the `MainImg` object. you need to use `using {}` block to make sure that objects are disposed properly.

Replace This:

```
Bitmap MainImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(txtLoginImage.Text);    
Bitmap NewImage = ConvertToGrayScale(MainImg);    
NewImage.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Temp\\"
                         + strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
NewImage.Dispose();
```

With This:

```
using(Bitmap MainImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(txtLoginImage.Text))            
using(Bitmap NewImage = ConvertToGrayScale(MainImg))
{
  NewImage.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Temp\\" + 
                     strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);      
}
```

**EDIT:**

Replace This:

```
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.UriSource = SourceUri;
```

With This:

```
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = SourceUri;
source.EndInit();
```

Comment: Still it does not allow me to delete. I think the reason is source object is using the file and it does not release the file after operation. I also tried setting source=null as source is of BitmapImage type object and it does not have Dispose() method

Comment: still the same error. Is there any way to forcefully delete used files?